# Can I execute as/nasm commands from a C program?

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

Im writing a simple compiler for my own programming language.
After the compiler generate the `.s` file I need to assemble it and I chose to use `as` since im on MacOS(ARM64).

These are the commands that I execute to assemble and link my .s file:

```bash
as -arch arm64 examples/build/main.s -o examples/build/main.o` 
ld -macosx_version_min 13.0.0 examples/build/main.o -o examples/build/main -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e main -arch arm64
```

When I execute these manually in the CL, everything works just fine and the program compile successfully, but when I try to use the C function `system`, im not able to successfully assemble the program.
Also, even if I execute `system(as)` and then `ld` manually Im not able to compile.

This is the error that I get:

```bash
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Using `_start` instead of `main` as label of the entry point label changes nothing.

### Assembly code

As you can see below, the program that Im trying to compile is really basic:

```
.global main
.align 2
main:
    mov X0, 10
    mov X16, 1
    svc 0
```

## C Code

Here you can take a look at the code that I use to call `as` and `ld` from C. `output_asm` contains the output path and has the `.s` file extension appended at the end, while `args->output_path` is the output path without any extension.

```
    char as[256];
    sprintf(as, "as -arch arm64 %s -o %s.o", output_asm, args->output_path);
    char ld[256];
    sprintf(ld, "ld -macosx_version_min 13.0.0 %s.o -o %s -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e main -arch arm64"
            , args->output_path, args->output_path);

            
    if (system(as) != 0)
    {
        exit(SWOOSHIFY_ERROR_ASSEMBLY_FAILED);
    }
    if (system(ld) != 0)
    {
        exit(SWOOSHIFY_ERROR_LINKING_FAILED);
    }
```

Can someone help me? thanks!

Comment: For debug purposes, you could nm the .o file before you try to link it, and verify that it contains the `main` symbol - this would tell you if the `as` command worked correctly. This too can be done with a `system` call. Because you're not sharing the code that's performing the `system` calls, we can only guess at what's gone wrong.

Comment: I edited the question so that it contains the C code.

Comment: LLVM has a built-in assembler; you might be able to JIT assemble a function into memory inside your process.  Actually other libraries might be more convenient for just assembling text into a buffer that you can call via a function pointer.  Of course, if you have assembly-language programs that aren't just functions that return, you would need to assemble + link them and fork+exec (or spawn) them as a separate process, e.g. if they do stuff like redirecting FDs, calling `exit`, or in fact calling any library function unless your JIT is fancy.

Comment: Notwithstanding Peter's comment, which is probably a better option in the long run, printf the system commands that you're invoking to ensure that what you _think_ is being run is what's being run; because … it worked on my machine when I wrapped this in a simple main wrapper.

Comment: The `system` function is part of the libc, should you link with `-lc` to use it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I'm already linking with `-lc` since I'm using CMake to build the project and it does it automatically.

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans the commands that are at the top of the question have been generated using my C script.

Comment: @Menga The commands you show above do not have `-lc` and thus will not include libc in the link.

Comment: I did not know that! how do I include libc in the linker then?

Comment: On OSX, the `System` library will also include libc, and the libc functionality, so this piece is a _little_ bit of a red herring. I'll reiterate my previous comment - `printf` the commands that are being invoked for `system`, to verify what you're invoking in `system` matches the debug effort on the command line; because as I mentioned before, when I took your sample code (ever so slightly modified), wrapped it in a main function and invoked it against the sample .s file, I had a binary that exited with `10`. I did see build warnings, but that's because I'm on Sonoma.

Comment: Ok guys I fixed it.. I was not flushing and closing the .asm file that I was generating, so `as` was reading an empty file.. this is so annoying.
Thanks everyone anyway!